# Symfony/Doctrine: Unserialize in action vs template

Tags: php, templates, symfony1, doctrine, serialization

Can anyone tell me why calling "unserialize" works fine in an action but gives an offset error in a template?

It's basically possible to unserialize a database text result into a variable in an action and pass it to template, in which case it displays fine:

```
$this->clean = unserialize($this->raw);
<?php echo $clean ?>
```

But not if called directly in a template:

```
<?php echo unserialize($raw) ?>
```

Would be interested in knowing why this is so and whether there's some workaround.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony puts all template variables into a `sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator` class. So when you write `unserialize($var)`, you are actually trying to unserialize the sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator class.

I recommend turning off output escaping in settings.yml:

```
escaping_strategy:     false
```

It is a stupid, performance-slaughtering, unnecessary feature of Symfony that needs murdered.

**Updated**:

If you turn off escaping_strategy, you will need to manually escape input from the users (to prevent XSS) with `htmlSpecialCharacters()`.

The Symfony class does that for you, but that means it also escapes every single number and character -- 99% of which you already know will be safe (IDs, dates, your own content). When I turned off the automatic escaping, my server load fell significantly.

Keep in mind that Symfony **double-applies** this automatic escaping if you pass a `sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator` to a partial, meaning `>` will become `&amp;gt;`

Comment: @Coronatus... ah, that makes sense. If I turn the escaping strategy off, what else can I expect to change? (unless this is something I should be reading up on properly)

Comment: Also, I'd be really interested in hearing how it's performance-slaughtering?